# Remove spacing between bar in bar graph( react-chart-js)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

issue that i am facing is, i have my bar graph made using react-chart-js. i want to remove space between the bar and center align  the bar's . The bar's should have Thickness equal to 50 [image: current output]

I try using dummy data ,that way i got the desired output but that is not the correct way of doing . Also I try using barPercentage , categoryPercentage option but didnt get the desired output [image: desired output]

[Link for CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-rhodes-yr2bl9?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this actually works out of the box. There is nothing in the documentation about this use case either.

You could do it with ghost values to extend the chart in general.
This is not really a solution, but it may be an option.

```
const labels = ["","","January", "February", "March","",""];

export const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Dataset 1",
      data: labels.map((elem, index) => {
          if (index > 1 && index < 5)
            return faker.datatype.number({ min: 0, max: 1000 })          
        }),
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
      barThickness: 50
    }
  ]
};
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah this can be a way but It would be great if we able to achieve desired output without using any dummy data